# How to Deserialize JSON object with dynamic variable names to a Java POJO?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

I am trying to parse the following nested JSON object using RestTemplate's `getForObject` method:

```
  "rates":{
    "USD":1.075489,
    "AUD":1.818178,
    "CAD":1.530576,
    "PLN":4.536389,
    "MXN":25.720674
  }
```

The number of currency rates varies depending on user input (it can be one or more).

How can I map such list of objects or a HashMap to a Java POJO class?

I tried with composition in the `rates` object:

```
public class Rates implements Serializable {

    private List<ExternalApiQuoteCurrencyRate> list;

     // getter and no-args constructor
}

public class ExternalApiQuoteCurrencyRate implements Serializable {

    private String currency;
    private BigDecimal rate;

    // getters and no-args constructor
}
```

But the `rates` object gets deserialized as `null`.

Could somebody please help? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What about rates being a Map<String, BigDecimal >

Comment: I tried it, Rates still arrives as null - I added the following variable in Rates: private Map<String, BigDecimal> rates;

Comment: Your JSON structure suggests fields called 'USD', 'AUD' etc. You won't be able to deserialize that into a POJO. How about returning a Map<String, Serializable> from the RestTemplate? (that's possibly what @bhspencer meant)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pushing me in the right direction guys.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Simon and @bhspencer I solved the issue by exporting the JSON object to a HashMap using `JsonNode`.

Here is the solution:

```
  ResponseEntity<JsonNode> e = restTemplate.getForEntity(API_URL, JsonNode.class);
  JsonNode map = e.getBody(); // this is a key-value list of all properties for this object
  // but I wish to convert only the "rates" property into a HashMap, which I do below:
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Map<String, BigDecimal> exchangeRates = mapper.convertValue(map.get("rates"), new TypeReference<Map<String, BigDecimal>>() {});
```